How to use kwalletcli to get a password?
Looking for a way to save passwords that I would use in bash scripts.
On my KDE-plasma desktop, I can open "Wallet Manager" a GUI interface to show and manage passwords.

I installed kwalletcli to access those passwords from command line:
apt install kwalletcli

And trying to get the password:
# Usage: kwalletcli -f folder -e entry [-P | -p writepassword]
kwalletcli -f "Folder/subfolder" -e "keyname"

When doing so, it open a GUI to create a new wallet. But I need to access kdewallet not create a new one:

Accepting and creating a new wallet does not work neither:
kf.i18n: KLocalizedString: Using an empty domain, fix the code. msgid: "KWallet CLI" msgid_plural: "" msgctxt: ""
folder 'Folder/subfolder' does not exist


The error message is folder 'Folder/subfolder' does not exist you are trying to access a folder in your wallet, that does not exist.
